# Rails method that handles ajax complaining about no template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `subscriber#create` method that is only used for ajax submits to it (the html form uses `data-remote="true"` to do the Ajax. The form does indeed submit and the data ends up in the db but the method throws an error saying that the template was not found.

**How can I specify a function as being an Ajax handler in Rails?** -- one that doesn't have to render a template, etc.

Here is what the method looks like:

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    Subscriber.create(:email          => params[:email],
                      :ip_address     => request.remote_ip,
                      :referring_page => request.referer ) unless Subscriber.find_by_email(params[:email])
  end

end
```

Comment: Please post the code from your controller's `create` method.

Comment: I've added it in to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the call in your respond_to properly.

```
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.js   { :nothing => true }
end
```

The thing it, you should probably return **something**.  Even if it is an AJAX call, you should send something back to let the caller know that the creation was a success.

```
def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(#your params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @subscriber.save
      format.js { render :json => @subscriber, :status => :created, :location => @susbscriber }
    else
      format.js { render :json => @susbcriber.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Also, you shouldn't have to do the `unless Subscriber.find_by_email(params[:email])` in your controller.  You should just add `validates_uniqueness_of :email` to the Subscriber model.

Comment: is the `format.html` needed as this function is only for ajax

Comment: No, I just put it there as a placeholder.  You can take it out.  :-)

Comment: I get a `syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}' format.js   { :nothing => true }` error.

Comment: I've updated my answer to say that you should return __something__.  You need some way of notifying the caller that the operation was a success.

Comment: No, but you'll need to change the code in your controllers just a bit to do it.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: In Rails 5, use `head :ok` instead of `render nothing: true`.

Answer (score 0):

you want something like `render :layout => !request.xhr?` in your controller, this will prevent the layout if the request is ajax

Comment: Just tried putting it at the bottom of the method, didn't work :(