# How to make AJAX responses work from the Rails side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**The HTML form:**

```
<form id="newsletter" method="post" action="/subscribers" data-remote="true">
    <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="text" />
    <p class="btn"><span>Signup</span></p>
</form>
```

Note the `data-remote="true"`

**The Controller:**

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.create(:email      => params[:email],
                                    :ip_address => request.remote_ip )

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**The View (subscribers/create.js.erb)**

```
no clue what goes here to make it return normal AJAX response (or error if it encountered one
```

**1. What do i put in the view to make it return normal ajax response or error?** -- Is it even needed to begin with (can I return this without creating such views)

**2. Is this the correct way of doing ajax with Rails?**

Comment: I gave an answer to almost this same exact question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196666/rails-method-that-handles-ajax-complaining-about-no-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks exactly like a question that I just answered today for another user...  same model names and everything.

```
def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(#your params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @subscriber.save
      format.js { render :json => @subscriber, :status => :created, :location => @susbscriber }
    else
      format.js { render :json => @susbcriber.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Also, you shouldn't have to do the `unless Subscriber.find_by_email(params[:email])` in your controller.  You should just add `validates_uniqueness_of :email` to the Subscriber model.

In the .erb file that contains the form, you would add the following javascript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // create a convenient toggleLoading function
  var toggleLoading = function() { $("#loading").toggle() };

  $("#your-form")
    .bind("ajax:loading",  toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:complete", toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
      $("#response").html(data);
    });
    .bind("ajax:failure", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
      //your code
    });
});
```

Comment: This code works with Rails 3.x; it will not work with Rails 2.x.  Specifically, what version of Rails are you using?  That will change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A standard respond_to block (this allows both html and js) would be:

```
respond_to do |format|  
  if @subscriber.save  
    format.html { redirect_to(@subscriber, :notice => 'Subscriber created.') }  
    format.js # Not redirecting, just spitting out the JSON(js?) response (I believe).  
  else  
    format.html { render :action => "new" }  
    format.js # Not redirecting for js and this time return error response. 
  end  
end
```

So what you have actually looks ok to me. Is it working ok or is there an issue?

The above should work with rails2 and rails3. Rails3 has a more succint syntax (of course) but given you are Rails2 I'll leave that for now.