# How do I get my js.erb file to render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `js.erb` file won't appear in Rails 3.1.2 and it's really confusing me. I'm including it in `app/views/items`. I have this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :action => :index }
  format.js {render :content_type => 'text/javascript' }
end
```

and it's named correctly. I've tried different combinations of names, but I don't even understand how the js.erb gets included because it's not in my source code. I put an `alert('hello');` in the `js.erb` and it won't run.

Comment: I can see the js file if I go to localhost/items/index.js. It's not included though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `js.erb` is the same name as the controller action, and `request.xhr?` is true, then it will automatically render the `js.erb`.  In the `respond_to` block, remove the code after `format.js` so that it looks like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :action => :index }
  format.js
end
```

Just be sure that the link activating this has `remote => true`, for example `link_to 'Some action', some_action_path, :remote => true`.

Comment: If I press control +u, should I be able to see a link to the js file?

Comment: If you're talking about the rendered `link_to` links, then no.  You will see a link to your controller.  Once you click on that link, you will see javascript returned and executed.  You can change the behavior of callbacks.  I gave an example of how to do that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8197130/367611.